# Show correct up/down arrow with Bootstrap panel when expanded by default

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So right now I have up/down arrows working as intended (down when the panel is closed, up when it is expanded). The problem is, I want the first card to be expanded by default, but the arrow is then pointing down, instead of up. Is there a work-around for that?

```css
/*my_css_file.css*/

.panel-title {
    position: relative;
  }


.panel-title::after {
  content: "\f078";
  color: #333;
  top: -2px;
  right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "FontAwesome"
}

  .panel-title[aria-expanded="true"]::after {
    content: "\f077";
  }

  /*
   * Added 12-27-20 to showcase full title clickthrough
   */

  .panel-heading-full.panel-heading {
    padding: 0;
  }

  .panel-heading-full .panel-title {
    padding: 10px 15px;
  }

  .panel-heading-full .panel-title::after {
    top: 10px;
    right: 15px;
  }
```

```html
/* my_html.hmtl */

<div class="content-section">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

    <!-- First Panel -->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">Tracked links</h4>
      </div>

      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse show">
        <div class="panel-body">
  
                CONTENT FOR CARD 1 (expanded by default)
               

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Second Panel -->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo">Link queue</h4>
      </div>

      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">

              content for card 2

          
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap wants the aria-expanded attribute. You can initially set it to true for your first card and false for your second card

```
<div class="content-section">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

        <!-- First Panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true">Tracked links</h4>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse show">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    CONTENT FOR CARD 1 (expanded by default)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <!-- Second Panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false">Link queue</h4>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                content for card 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```